# Ruby string to array conversion using 'scan' function

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
"10/2+3*3/2-3/2+10"
```

I need to convert it to an array:

```
["10", "/", "2", "+", "3", "*", "3", "/", "2", "-", "3", "/", "2", "+", "10"]
```

without using any gem.

I am using the following code to try to convert it:

```
"10/2+3*3/2-3/2+10".scan(/[\d*,+,\-,*,\/]/)
# => ["1", "0", "/", "2", "+", "3", "*", "3", "/", "2", "-", "3", "/", "2", "+", "1", "0"]
```

The output is not what I was expecting.

Comment: This is not an "i want" site.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno what do you mean, I am not getting you?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Your answer was very clean. If you didn't like the fact that you had to get rid of the first element, then you can use `\D` instead of `\d`, assuming that the string doesn't start with an operator.

Comment: @sawa, thanks. I will update as a community wiki.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I got your point, Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-split)

```
"10/2+3*3/2-3/2+10".split(/(\D)/)
#=> ["10", "/", "2", "+", "3", "*", "3", "/", "2", "-", "3", "/", "2", "+", "10"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Commas inside square brackets in regular expression are treated as commas. What you want is the union of patterns.

```
"10/2+3*3/2-3/2+10".scan(/\d+|\+|\*|\/|\-/)
```

Comment: Or `/\d+|[+*\/-]/` or without having to quote the slash: `%r{\d+|[+*/-]}`

Answer (score 1):

```
"10/2+3*3/2-3/2+10".scan(/\d+|./)
  #=> ["10", "/", "2", "+", "3", "*", "3", "/", "2", "-", "3", "/", "2", "+", "10"]
```